# How can I create a Graph in CosmosDB from Code

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

If I want to connect to CosmosDB which is created with Gemlin API is works fine with [Gremlin.Net](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.7/reference/#gremlin-DotNet)

But the Gremlin.NET API is designed to handle on Graph. I think because the Neo4j and other Graph databases can handle one graph in one time. And I want a new a Graph in CosmosDB I can create it from [Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-java#add-a-graph).

But How can I create a new Graph from Code? 
Of course when I connect to same CosmosDB instance with DocumentDB API, then I Can create a new Collection which is Graph in Cosmos. But this is not safe for some reason:

1. Not recommended to Connect to Cosmos with Different API-s.
2. When I create a Graph from Azure Portal, maybe there is some other initialization code is running, other than just create an empty collection

Is there a safe way to create Graph In CosmosDB from Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization code only runs when you create a Cosmos DB account with Gremlin API. The initialization code creates a Gremlin webseocket server endpoint which is specific to Gremlin API.

After that, creating a Graph is equivalent to creating a collection/container  using the Document DB API.

Please send us an email at askCosmosDBGraphAPI@microsoft.com.

Jayanta